# PDO fetch obj with defined objectname

Tags: php, pdo

Similar too:

```
PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE
```

I want to do the same with:

```
PDO::FETCH_OBJ
```

Means I want to pick each row as an object named by the first value.

Example:

```
id name url
1  Test www.test.de
2  Test2 www.test2.de

Select name, id, url FROM whatever;

$processes = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

returns the objects idexed from 0 - x

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP)
```

Returns it nearly like I want just 2 downsides:

```
   test {
      0: [
        'id': 1,
        'src': 'www.test.de'
      ]
    }
```

First is I want to keep name in the object (could douple select (select name, name ...) and I have the unecessary array inside.

So any idea how I get it to this:

```
test [
        'name': 'test',
        'id': 1,
        'src': 'www.test.de'
      ]
test2 [
        'name': 'test2',
        'id': 2,
        'src': 'www.test2.de'
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my;host=localhost', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, id, name, url FROM data");
$sth->execute();

var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ | PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE));
```

The output will be like this:

```
array(3) {
  'test 1' =>
  class stdClass#6 (3) {
    public $id =>
    string(1) "4"
    public $name =>
    string(6) "test 1"
    public $url =>
    string(13) "www.gmail.com"
  }
  'test 2' =>
  class stdClass#4 (3) {
    public $id =>
    string(1) "2"
    public $name =>
    string(6) "test 2"
    public $url =>
    string(14) "www.google.com"
  }
  'test 3' =>
  class stdClass#5 (3) {
    public $id =>
    string(1) "3"
    public $name =>
    string(6) "test 3"
    public $url =>
    string(21) "www.stackoverflow.com"
  }
}
```

But be noticed: if you add duplicate values into the `name` column, you will get values of last record with the same name. In my example above I have table with this dataset:

```
select * from data;
+----+--------+-----------------------+
| id | name   | url                   |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | test 1 | www.ya.ru             |
|  2 | test 2 | www.google.com        |
|  3 | test 3 | www.stackoverflow.com |
|  4 | test 1 | www.gmail.com         |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

So you have data from record with ID = 4 in object named "test 1".